# Change Maximum connections in chrome, similar to what is in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, http, request

I would like to be able to modify some parameters of red del browser chrome, I'm not sure if they are possible, but if something I need to do.

In firefox when I enter about:config , I can modify 2 parameters that I need network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server and network.http.max-connections-per-server .

How can I do it myself in chrome? .

In the chrome configuration part I can't find anything about it, in the network part it only takes me to my hardware network but there is nothing to modify